# Simple LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have a List of X items.  I want to have LINQ query that will convert it into batches (a List of Lists), where each batch has 4 items, except for the last one which can have 1-4 (whatever the remainder is).  Also, the number 4 should be configurable so it could 5, 17, etc.

Can anyone tell me how to write that?

```
List<Item> myItems = ...;
List<List<Item>> myBatches = myItems.????
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy with the results being typed as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` then you can do this:

```
int groupSize = 4;

var myBatches = myItems.Select((x, i) => new { Val = x, Idx = i })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Idx / groupSize,
                                x => x.Val);
```

If you want an actual `List<List<T>>` then you'll need to add a couple of extra [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) calls:

```
int groupSize = 4;

var myBatches = myItems.Select((x, i) => new { Val = x, Idx = i })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Idx / groupSize,
                                x => x.Val,
                                (k, g) => g.ToList())
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Using_Take_and_Skip_method_in_LINQ_queries.aspx) is a good article about using [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) to do paging, which is identical functionality to what you are requesting.  It doesn't get you all of the way to a single line of LINQ, but hopefully helps.

Answer (score 0):

This made me think of how we did this before LINQ.

```
var vessels = new List<Vessel>() 
    { new Vessel() { id =  8, name = "Millennium Falcon" }, 
      new Vessel() { id =  4, name = "Ebon Hawk" },
      new Vessel() { id = 34, name = "Virago"},
      new Vessel() { id = 12, name = "Naboo royal starship"},
      new Vessel() { id = 17, name = "Radiant VII"},
      new Vessel() { id =  7, name = "Lambda-class shuttle"},
      new Vessel() { id = 23, name = "Rogue Shadow"}};

var chunksize=2;

// With LINQ                 
var vesselGroups = vessels.Select((v, i) => new { Vessel = v, Index = i })
                          .GroupBy(c => c.Index / chunksize, c => c.Vessel, (t,e)=>e.ToList())
                          .ToList();

// Before LINQ (most probably not optimal)
var groupedVessels = new List<List<Vessel>>();
var g = new List<Vessel>();
var chunk = chunksize;
foreach(var vessel in vessels)
{
    g.Add(vessel);
    chunk--;
    if (chunk == 0)
    {
        groupedVessels.Add(g);
        g = new List<Vessel>();
        chunk = chunksize;
    }
}
groupedVessels.Add(g);
```